# Bridge - Standard American

Tags: bridge

While playing 2 over 1 where a responders bid of 2 in a new suit shows 13 or more points (we open with 12 points) and is game forcing then a 1NT response to a Major opening by partner would show upto 12 points (is that right?)

And to a 1 of a minor opening bid it would show upto 10 points.

So, the bidding goes:

N    E    S   W
1H/S  P   1NT  P ... 1NT bid shows up to 12 points and is one round forcing ?

1d/c  P   1NT  P ... 1NT bid shows up to 10 points and is NOT forcing ?

How do you tell when a responder is using a 6-9 point non-forcing 1NT versus a 6-12 point forcing 1NT?

Comment: Which ONE question are you asking? If you wish to ask more than one question, then create multiple questions; or remove the rhetorical questions and simply state your assumptions around the ONE questionyou ish to ask. **DON'T MAKE US INVENT YOUR SYSTEM** - as we do not have the benefit of partnership discussion with your partner.

Comment: This is a single "comparison and contrast" question. How do you tell when partner is responding with a 6-9 point non-forcing one no trump, versus a 6-12 point forcing?

Comment: I will take a stab at your final question: "How do you tell when a responder is using a 6-9 point non-forcing 1NT vs a 6-12 point forcing 1NT?"  With current ACBL rules, opener is required to announcing "Forcing" if their partnership agreement is as such.  [Presumably if it is YOUR partner who is bidding 1NT after your major opening, you already know which system you're playing and can announce the "Forcing" yourself.]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your suppositions are correct. But it's best not to have to work all this out yourself. Are you following a system from a book or web site? If not I suggest you do. You can always vary what you learn later.

Comment: Thanks...which is the best site you would recommend?

Comment: Here's one: http://web2.acbl.org/documentlibrary/play/SP3%20(bk)%20single%20pages.pdf

Comment: And another: http://www.fifthchair.org/archive/annam/2-1.pdf

Comment: I have no insight into which is best, if any. I've been playing long enough that I learned using other sources.